# React.js: Get a specific string from a useState array

Tags: reactjs

I have this useState array named `profileModule`

It contains this if I use console.log

```
(1) […]
​
0: Object { moduleId: "4E948025-1F1B-41E2-A18D-55AD8646810B", module: "Client Maintenance", description: "Client Enrollment", … }
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: []
```

What I want to do is just get moduleId value as a string. Therefore, coming up with:
`4E948025-1F1B-41E2-A18D-55AD8646810B`

I have tried many things like map, spread, etc. I'm very confused right now how to accomplish such a simple feat.

TIA to those who would help

EDIT:
Actual code

```
const [profileModule, setProfileModule] = useState([]) 

const selectRowClient = {
    mode: 'checkbox',
    clickToSelect: true,
    clickToEdit: false,
    hideSelectAll: false,
    hideSelectColumn: false,
    onSelect: (row, isSelect, rowIndex, e) => {
      setProfileName(row.profileName)
      if( isSelect === true ){
        profileModuleId.push(row.id) // for multiple delete 
      } 
      ProfileMaintenanceService.retrieveProfileDetails(row.id)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("ProfileMaintenancePage - retrieveProfileDetails response.data >>> ", response.data)
        setProfileModule(response.data)
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("ProfileMaintenancePage - retrieveProfileDetails catch >>> ", err)
      })
    }
  };

return (
<BootstrapTable
              keyField='id'
              hover
              data={ profiles }
              columns={ columnsProfile }
              filter={ filterFactory() }
              selectRow={ selectRowClient }
              noDataIndication="No record(s) found."
              pagination={ paginationFactory(options) }
            />
)
```

Comment: Is what you're asking that you want this line `setProfileModule(response.data)` to instead update the state to only contain the string `moduleId`?

Comment: What is the question? How to access the array? `profileModule[0].moduleId`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In that specific case simply

```
profileModule[0].moduleId
```

should give you the `moduleId` of the first item.

If you want to get a list of all module ids, do

```
const moduleIds = profileModule.map(module => module.moduleId);
```

Comment: This works great. What if I want to get the deeper value of a JSON, if I want to get actionId e.g. `[
    {
        "actions": [
            {
                "actionId": "C7FCD770-7868-4357-8CA6-57A5C4DA1F1E",
                "action": "ClientDetailsNew",
                "description": "Enroll new Customer for Pesonet"
            }
        ]
    }
]`

Answer (score 0):

Since your result is an array containing one element, you can access the string using this code: `response.data[0].moduleId` This gets the module id first element of the array, and returns it. You can use this like this:

```
console.log(response.data[0].moduleId);
```

or in this case, use it like this:

```
setProfileModule(response.data[0].moduleId);
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. So I can only do the index thing on the response itself, not on the state array? e.g. I set the value of response.data on `setProfiles`, can I do `profiles[0].moduleId`?